# How to handle dynamic JSON elements in Groovy

Tags: java, grails, groovy

I have JSON that looks similar to this:

> {"test":{"red":"on","green":"off","yellow":"on"},"test1":{"red":"off","green":"on","yellow":"off"},"test2":{"red":"on","green":"off","yellow":"off"}}

I've iterating over this with the code below:

```
    JSONObject t = JSON.parse(params.myObject)

    t.each { id, data ->
        println id
        println data.red
        println data.green
        println data.yellow
    }
```

However, at times I can have dynamically different values in the JSON Object. For example (new color added):

{"test":{"red":"on","green":"off","yellow":"on","pink":"on"},"test1":{"red":"off","green":"on","yellow":"off","pink":"on"},"test2":{"red":"on","green":"off","yellow":"off","pink":"on"}}

**Question**

Is there a way to iterate over all the json without hardcoding the colors in my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
JSONObject t = JSON.parse(params.myObject)
t.each { id, data ->
    println id
    data.each { prop, value ->
       println prop + " = " + value
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

I can simply just iterate over the values in similar fashion:

```
    t.each { id, data ->
        println id
        data.each {id1, d ->
            println id1
            println  d
        }
    }
```